# Error in using `gcloud.auth.application-default.login` cmd in gcloud CLI

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, gcloud, skaffold

I am learning Kubernetes in GCP. To deploy the cluster into google cloud, I used skaffold. Following is the YAML file:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  # local:
  #   push: false
  googleCloudBuild:
    projectId: ticketing-dev-368011
  artifacts:
    - image: gcr.io/{project-id}/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "src/**/*.ts"
            dest: .
```

In google cloud CLI, when I give the CLI command `skaffold dev`, the error popped up saying:

```
getting cloudbuild client: google: could not find default credentials.
```

Then I give the command in my local terminal `gcloud auth application-default login`, I was prompted to give consent on the browser, and I gave consent and the page was redirected to a page "successfull authentication". But When I see my terminal, there is an error message showing as
`Error saving Application Default Credentials: Unable to write file [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json]: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`

And I found there is no such file being created in the above directory. Can someone please help me What I have done wrong?

Comment: I think your approach is correct. `gcloud` **should** succeed in creating the file `application_default_credentials.json` (and that should solve the default credentials problem). That it's failing is the problem. Does that folder exist? Can you try manually creating a file (any other name) in that folder? I'm not familiar with Windows but it's slightly curious that your username is `Admin`. I think it's probably a red-herring but I would expect this to be a non-Admin username.

Comment: Thank you. I am using windows 10. I tried using the terminal to run as an administrator. But getting the same error.  When I see the logs, I got the token as follows: `{'access_token': 'xxxx', 'expires_in': 3599, 'refresh_token': 'xxxx', 'scope': [...], 'token_type': 'Bearer', 'id_token': xxxx', 'expires_at': 1667997097.4593372}`  . So I manually created `application_default_credentials.json` file on the directory and tried using the command `skaffold dev`. At this time it says the token does not have type.

Comment: I've not used `skaffold dev` but generally I think you don't want to run as admin/root. The `application_default_credentials.json` is an OAuth2 Client ID. It has structure `{"client_id":"","client_secret":"","refresh_token":"","type":"authorized_user"}` and is distinct from the token. It's interesting that you are receiving an access token correctly in the logs. I'm reluctant to suggest an alternative because I don't know that it will work for you **but** it should. Can you please try creating a Service Account (rather than using `gcloud auth application-default`.